# Faster way for this mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$handle = fopen("stock.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {
    $model = mysql_real_escape_string ($data[0]);
    $quantity = mysql_real_escape_string ($data[7]);
mysql_select_db("verradt33_xoho", $link);

$quantity = str_replace("JA", "10", $quantity);
$quantity = str_replace("NEE", "0", $quantity);

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE dev_product 
    SET quantity = $quantity
    WHERE model = '$model'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Even tho the code works, it takes a long time to process the 7000+ lines in the CSV. Due to having to replace JA or NEE with 10 or 0 every single line.

Is there a way to make this faster? I can't touch the csv file, that's the hard part of course.

Current load time is 40 minutes.

Comment: I'd try moving `mysql_select_db("verradt33_xoho", $link);` outside the loop. Also, I doubt the `str_replace`s would make things go slower in any measurable way. I'd check that `model` has an index to start with.

Comment: Is there an index on `model`?

Comment: So what exactly takes how long with what you do? To improve such you need to metric first, everything else is guessing around. E.g. if reading the CSV file is fast (I guess) but running the SQL query is slow, then you need to optimize/upgrade your Mysql server, there is not much you can do in code.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: you could use a single `str_replace` ie `str_replace(array('JA','NEE'), array('10', '0'), $quantity)`

Comment: First question should be `Is the model column indexed`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yeah. But the problem is that OP most likely will ask back: What does it mean? Next to that it's also important to know for example, which storage engine is used. But I didn't ask for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question should be: **Is the column `model` indexed?**

Secondly, try commenting out the database access's and see how long it takes just to do the .csv processing!

```
mysql_select_db("verradt33_xoho", $link);
$handle = fopen("stock.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {
    $model = mysql_real_escape_string ($data[0]);
    $quantity = mysql_real_escape_string ($data[7]);

    $quantity = str_replace("JA", "10", $quantity);
    $quantity = str_replace("NEE", "0", $quantity);
    /*
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE dev_product 
                           SET quantity = $quantity
                           WHERE model = '$model'")  or  die(mysql_error());
    */
}
```

If that finishes in seconds then its definitely you database accesses that are causing the speed issues.

Suggestion: You only seem to be changing `JA` and `NEE` to numerics so keep it simple

```
mysql_select_db("verradt33_xoho", $link);
$handle = fopen("stock.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {
    $model = mysql_real_escape_string ($data[0]);
    $quantity = mysql_real_escape_string ($data[7]);

    switch ($quantity) {
        case 'JA'     : $quantity = 10; break;
        case 'NEE'    : $quantity = 0;  break;
    }

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE dev_product 
                           SET quantity = $quantity
                           WHERE model = '$model'")  or  die(mysql_error());

}
```

But your best hope for instant speed is to index the `model` column.

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly, gonne try your solution now!

Comment: Indexing did the trick, code changes made no noticeable changes.

Comment: @StefanFielemon Thats what I expected, the code changes just cleaned up some rough edges.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make this faster?

Yes it is. I assume you are merely having speed issues because of the way you do the database update operations which look highly non-optimized to me.

The Mysql manual covers the topic here: [Speed of UPDATE Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update-speed.html) and hints / references the important resources from there. A key suggestion I'd like to highlight in the context of your question is the following:

> Another way to get fast updates is to delay updates and then do many updates in a row later. Performing multiple updates together is much quicker than doing one at a time if you lock the table.

So I really suggest you to do that now if you're concerned about speed. Group the updates, e.g. collect 10 lines from CSV and then do 10 updates at once. Make it configureable with parameters so you can extend the chunks to 100 or 1000.

---

However the downside with all these suggestions is that their optimizations are far too limited. Instead if you are really looking for *speed* you need to optimize your import process.

The accepted practice to update from a CSV file is outlined in a previous question so I don't have to repeat it in full length:

- [Update MySQL Table using CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11019255/367456)

The benefit here is that you can quickly import (batch insert into temporary table) and then fire an update query in the multi-table syntax. That's just really faster.

For the string manipulation, you can either solve that by working with pipes while importing or but updating the temporary table with mysql string functions.

As all this runs on the database server itself, it's just much more faster.

Answer (score 0):

**Replacing directly in SQL the strings you need, instead of using PHP** will leave some of the hard work to the database server, it will be much faster. Can't test right now, but I think this can handle it for you.

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE dev_product 
    SET quantity = (REPLACE(REPLACE($quantity, 'JA', '10') , 'NEE', '10')
    WHERE model = '$model'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Apart of that you could try:

- **Group each 10 updates in one single query, so we could reduce the number of queries executed by 1/10.**
- [**use temporary table to batch import a csv, then update the primary table**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019255/update-mysql-table-using-csv-file)
- [**strtr() is 4x faster than str_replace** *according to chazzuka.com*](http://www.chazzuka.com/63-best-practice-to-optimize-php-code-performances-58/)

You could use something like this:

```
$replace = array('JA'=>10, 'NEE'=>0);
$quantity = strtr($quantity, $replace);
```

- **create indexes in your database**

Having your main columns indexed, will reduce the searching time in the table you are updating.

Try doing an index in your **model** column (the column you are filtering when updating).

- **just select database once**

Your code is always selecting the database everytime it gets a line from the CSV.

Put the mysql_select_db just right before the loop.

- **use a database wrapper (like PDO, Mysqli, ..) - *off-topic advice***

This is a obvious one, but is all the way preferred over the deprecated use you are doin' it.

If you don't know what is PDO you could read something here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

I know some are just minor improvements but don't forget: *many minor improvements make the difference*.

Thanks to @hakre for some points.

Comment: And you know that str_replace was the bottleneck which took 32 of the 40 minutes, so that this "optimization" you suggest gains the OP 24 minutes, right? :) - If you didn't notice, you call that function wrong. And when you find out what I mean in the manual, take also the other hint so you don't need to call it twice :)

Comment: also I would be *very* interested to know how much really the superfluous database select call actually costs. You answer so sure, so may I ask what your metrics have revealed?

Comment: And last but not least the suggestion to use PDO, how does it relate to speed? Isn't it that under the hood both PDO and mysql_* use the same database driver library mysqlnd? Why is PDO faster, is it really obvious? Wouldn't it be more obvious to switch to mysqli_* instead for speed reasons?

Comment: Hello @hakre, thanks a lot for your comments. It's great to have some feedback. And from what I've read, I don't think I am calling that function wrong, but it could be better as you say (using the array method, that was what you were talking about, right?). I am gonna change the example to reflect that.

Comment: Well, first hint (from the manual): *"If from and to have different lengths, the extra characters in the longer of the two are ignored. The length of str will be the same as the return value's."* - so you actually didn't replace what you thought you would replace. The solution is easy: Use the array parameter. That even allows you to do it in one call.

Comment: I've done some local tests comparing both. In replacing some 6-length string, there are some differences, never the same, but somewhat noticeable. Using str_replace() usually gives me 0.00760s-0.0100s to replace 7000 results, as strtr() - using the string replacing example I've gave -, takes about 0.0045s-0.009s.

Comment: You see how low, how very very very very very very very very very very very  little amount of time you actually save here, right? It is so little that tasked with a real job, you would not even consider to care. However presented with such an "how to make it faster?" question, you feel motivated to care about - well what - nothing? - with passion.

Comment: And referring to PDO/mysqli: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421830/php-pdo-vs-normal-mysqli-speed

Comment: When you are really concerned, you metric the actual code. You don't link to some question (which has *very* vague answers btw. and if you look into the "tests" done - if any - well turn away :)), so please, I mean, take something from my comments or just let it. I think it's worth you learn about how `strtr` works because it's a good function, but for the speed optimizations, you need to metric first and then kill the bottleneck. Most likely in this question, the bottleneck is the whole procedure, see my answer, there are better ways to do it.

Comment: I think you understood me wrong. If so, apologize for that. I thought about linking the benchmarks, however, the conclusion of the post itself made my point, so I've paste the link. I liked some of the suggestions you made in your post, specially keeping at maximum all the hard-work at the database, to make it much more faster. Thanks for the feedback.